# Update an href on an IHTMLLinkElement

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, virtual

I need to update the contents of an href on an IHTMLLinkElement. What I've come up compiles but causes an error as soon as it's execute

```
static const CComBSTR href(L"http://www.google.com");
spLinkElement->put_href(href); // IHTMLLinkElement
```

The error I get is

```
Program: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPORER.EXE
File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h
Line: 154
```

Comment: That's the location of an error, not the error itself.  Was it an access violation?  An assert?  My copy of atlcomcli.h has a close brace  (`}`) on line 154.  Please provide more information.

Comment: OK, I looked in the output window in visual studio (yes, I'm very new to visual studio, second day) and I now see that the reported exception is: First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb in IEXPLORE.EXE: 0x800706BA: The RPC server is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if RPC service is enabled and running ...

Comment: I stopped getting the RPC server error after a reboot. Unfortunately, I now get nothing more than the error notification which doesn't include anything useful.